# Minifying HTML String React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, email, client-side

Is there any lib that can minify a HTML string client side just like html-minifier or html-minifier-terser server side?

I want to minify a string containing HTML of a email. Works fine server side like this:

```
const result = minify(testString, {
    collapseWhitespace: true,
    conservativeCollapse: true,
    trimCustomFragments: true,
    removeRedundantAttributes: true,
    removeEmptyAttributes: true,
    removeComments: true,
    minifyCSS: true,
    minifyJS: true,
    collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
});
```

By using html-minifier-terser. Is there anything similar working in React, client side?

Comment: Why don't you use the libraries you mentionned client side?

Comment: And also, what is your purpose when minifying this email markup, is it for cleaning or actullay reducing the size? How does using React change something from your point of view?

Comment: Already tried to use these libs client side. They are dependent on fs, and as far as i understand fs is for node server side.

Comment: I doubt they actually require fs when doing what your doing, but may require some treeshaking. I'll a have a deeper look into it. Are you using a bundler such as webpack?

Comment: Yes im using webpack as bundler. And thank you.

Comment: Can I ask again the ultimate goal? do you really need to minimize html or do you only need to clean it? and from what? is it only html or also css and js?